# Regarding ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: networking

I realise some website have multiple ipv4 addresses and some would only have one. Why is that so? is every website of ipv4 address always get the same address? why certain websites would have both ipv4 and ipv6 address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I realise some website have multiple ipv4 addresses and some would only have one. Why is that so?

Smaller websites only need one IP address. When a user visits a site, they are connected to the server at that IP address and are served content. Larger websites like Google/Apple/etc need multiple IP addresses so that all traffic is not routed in one direction. Ideally, the client would choose the route that is closest to them so the network would not get congested. Additionally, any site can pay for CDNs like [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) which gives the appears of a site having multiple ip addresses, but they all actually point to the CDN in order to reduce the load like I mentioned above.

> every website of ipv4 address always get the same address?

Normally no, IP addresses are not fixed and they will change. This change is usually unnoticeable due to [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), which allows the site to update its DNS records whenever the IP address changes. When a user attempts to connect to the site, a DNS lookup is made to determine the current IP address. It is, however, possible for large companies/schools to purchase IP address blocks in which case, the company gets to decide how to allocate the IP addresses and they can be fixed.

> why certain websites would have both ipv4 and ipv6 address?
>   ipv6 is a newer protocol than ipv4. Every website that was on ipv4 can still work today without supporting ipv6, so if the company/school/etc. chooses not to support ipv6 networking into their data center, they will not have an ipv6 address. It may cost money for them to implement, so they have chosen not to.

Comment: thanks so much, i just wonder what is current ratio of website that having ipv4 and ipv6 ?

Comment: From quick searching, according to google ~25% of websites are ipv6: https://www.google.com/intl/en/ipv6/statistics.html. This might be a good intro to traceroute: https://www.slashroot.in/how-does-traceroute-work-and-examples-using-traceroute-command